# A popup that slides, delays then slides out automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I'm trying to create a popup that slides in from the bottom right of the screen when the user performs an action, stays for a few seconds, then slides out. Something's **wrong** with my code. This is my JS:

```js
function showModal() {
  $('#sideModal').css('display', 'block').animate({
    width: '20%',
    display: 'block'
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000
  }).delay(9000).animate({
    width: '0',
    display: 'none'
  }, {
    duration: 1000
  });
  //$('#sideModal').css('display', 'none');I commented this out because this prevents the div showing in the first place.
}
```

```css
#sideModal {
    height: 75px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:35px;">
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="showModal()">Click Me</button>
<div id="sideModal">
  I'm a sliding modal
</div>
</div>
```

The div slides in and out as it should. However, the text remains. How can I fix this?

Comment: as a sidenote you cant animate display, there is just nothing like 50% block. you can use .fadeIn/.fadeOut for this, which animates over the opacity and sets it to block/none

Comment: @Dirk. Thank you for that. Must have forgotten animate also uses percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: hidden` to your `#sideModal`

```js
function showModal() {
  $('#sideModal').css('display', 'block').animate({
    width: '20%',
    display: 'block'
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000
  }).delay(9000).animate({
    width: '0',
    display: 'none'
  }, {
    duration: 1000
  });
  //$('#sideModal').css('display', 'none');I commented this out because this prevents the div showing in the first place.
}
```

```css
#sideModal {
    height: 75px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:35px;">
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="showModal()">Click Me</button>
<div id="sideModal">
  I'm a sliding modal
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow:hidden` to the modal so the text wont be visible if the modal is not.

[About overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```js
function showModal() {
  $('#sideModal').css('display', 'block').animate({
    width: '20%',
    display: 'block'
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000
  }).delay(9000).animate({
    width: '0',
    display: 'none'
  }, {
    duration: 1000
  });
  //$('#sideModal').css('display', 'none');I commented this out because this prevents the div showing in the first place.
}
```

```css
#sideModal {
    height: 75px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:35px;">
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="showModal()">Click Me</button>
<div id="sideModal">
  I'm a sliding modal
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it slide in from the right just change `left: 0;` to `right: 0;` like so:

```js
function showModal() {
  $('#sideModal').css('display', 'block').animate({
    right: '0%',
    display: 'block'
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000
  }).delay(4000).animate({
    right: '-20%',
    display: 'none'
  }, {
    duration: 1000
  });
  //$('#sideModal').css('display', 'none');I commented this out because this prevents the div showing in the first place.
}
```

```css
#sideModal {
    height: 75px;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: -20%;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:35px;">
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="showModal()">Click Me</button>
<div id="sideModal">
  I'm a sliding modal
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Made a few changes so that the text does not wrap when the modal appears/disappears.

Hope it helps